# In Java 8, why were Arrays not given the forEach method of Iterable?

Tags: java, arrays, foreach, java-8, javac

I must be missing something here.

In Java 5, the ["for-each loop" statement (also called the enhanced for loop)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) was introduced. It appears that it was introduced mainly to iterate through *Collections*. Any collection (or container) class that implements the [`Iterable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) interface is eligible for iteration using the "for-each loop". Perhaps for historic reasons, the Java arrays did not implement the `Iterable` interface. But since arrays were/are ubiquitous, `javac` would accept the use of for-each loop on arrays (generating bytecode equivalent to a traditional for loop).

In Java 8, the [`forEach` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-) was added to the `Iterable` interface as a *default* method. This made passing lambda expressions to collections (while iterating) possible (e.g. `list.forEach(System.out::println)`). But again, arrays don't enjoy this treatment. (I understand that there are workarounds).

Are there technical reasons why `javac` couldn't be enhanced to accept arrays in `forEach`, just like it accepts them in the enhanced for loop? It appears that code generation would be possible without requiring that arrays implement `Iterable`. Am I being naive?

This is especially important for a newcomer to the language who rather naturally uses arrays because of their syntactical ease. It's hardly natural to switch to Lists and use `Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3)`.

Comment: Probably because it's not worth it -- collections are so much easier to work with than arrays and when you need to use an array, `asList(myArray)` is a very simple workaround.

Comment: Are you kidding? They don't even have their own `toString()`.

Comment: What do you mean @Bohemian?

Comment: @MickMnemonic the Array objects don't have an implementation for `toString()` - they only have the default, and useless, impl of Object

Comment: Sounds like a question for the Java 8 team.

Comment: How do we know that answers will lack references without allowing the answers?

Comment: Natural or not, `List`s, and not arrays, are the standard and recommended list type in Java so you'd best embrace them.  No, it doesn't have syntactical support (though to be honest I don't use indexes for lists *or* arrays that often, it's much more common for maps).  Maybe that also hints at an answer to your question...that making it easier to use arrays in Java was hardly a priority--if even desirable.

Comment: An array can be converted into a Java 8 stream: `Arrays.stream(a).forEach(...);`. I don't know why this question was closed, there could have been great answers.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils Indeed....

Comment: @pp_ Or `Arrays.asList(a).forEach(`…`)` (which I think I prefer).

Answer (score 57, accepted):

There are a bunch of special cases in the Java language and in the JVM for arrays. Arrays have an API, but it's barely visible. It is as if arrays are declared to have:

- `implements Cloneable, Serializable`
- `public final int length`
- `public T[] clone()` where `T` is the array's component type

However, these declarations aren't visible in any source code anywhere. See [JLS 4.10.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.10.3) and [JLS 10.7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.7) for explanations. `Cloneable` and `Serializable` are visible via reflection, and are returned by a call to

```
Object[].class.getInterfaces()
```

Perhaps surprisingly, the `length` field and the `clone()` method aren't visible reflectively. The `length` field isn't a field at all; using it turns into a special `arraylength` bytecode. A call to `clone()` results in an actual virtual method call, but if the receiver is an array type, this is handled specially by the JVM.

Notably, though, array classes do not implement the `Iterable` interface.

When the enhanced-for loop ("for-each") was added in Java SE 5, it supported two different cases for the right-hand-side expression: an `Iterable` or an array type ([JLS 14.14.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2)). The reason is that `Iterable` instances and arrays are handled completely differently by the enhanced-for statement. That section of the JLS gives the full treatment, but put more simply, the situation is as follows.

For an `Iterable<T> iterable`, the code

```
for (T t : iterable) {
    <loop body>
}
```

is syntactic sugar for

```
for (Iterator<T> iterator = iterable.iterator(); iterator.hasNext(); ) {
    t = iterator.next();
    <loop body>
}
```

For an array `T[]`, the code

```
for (T t : array) {
    <loop body>
}
```

is syntactic sugar for

```
int len = array.length;
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    t = array[i];
    <loop body>
}
```

Now, why was it done this way? It would certainly be possible for arrays to implement `Iterable`, since they implement other interfaces already. It would also be possible for the compiler to synthesize an `Iterator` implementation that's backed by an array. (There is precedent for this. The compiler already synthesizes the static `values()` and `valueOf()` methods that are automatically added to every `enum` class, as described in [JLS 8.9.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9.3).)

But arrays are a very low-level construct, and accessing an array by an `int` value is expected to be extremely inexpensive operation. It's quite idiomatic to run a loop index from `0` to an array's length, incrementing by one each time. The enhanced-for loop on an array does exactly that. If the enhanced-for loop over an array were implemented using the `Iterable` protocol, I think most people would be unpleasantly surprised to discover that looping over an array involved an initial method call and memory allocation (creating the `Iterator`), followed by two method calls per loop iteration.

So when default methods were added to `Iterable` in Java 8, this didn't affect arrays at all.

As others have noted, if you have an array of `int`, `long`, `double`, or of reference type, it's possible to turn this into a stream using one of the `Arrays.stream()` calls. This provides access to `map()`, `filter()`, `forEach()`, etc.

It would be nice, though, if the special cases in the Java language and JVM for arrays were replaced by *real* constructs (along with fixing a bunch of other array-related problems, such as poor handling of 2+ dimensional arrays, the 2^31 length limitation, and so forth). This is the subject of the "Arrays 2.0" investigation being led by John Rose. See John's talk at JVMLS 2012 ([video](http://medianetwork.oracle.com/video/player/1785452137001), [slides](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~jrose/pres/201207-Arrays-2.pdf)). The ideas relevant to this discussion include introduction of an actual interface for arrays, to allow libraries to interpose element access, to support additional operations such as slicing and copying, and so forth.

Note that all of this is investigation and future work. There is nothing from these array enhancements that is committed in the Java roadmap for any release, as of this writing (2016-02-23).

Comment: Thank you for the more-or-less official perspective, references and above all, taking the time to write it all up! Although my observation was mainly about making both for-each and `forEach` behave as (naively) expected for arrays (and not about having arrays implement `Iterable`), your answer does provide some valuable insights.

Comment: woaah genius boii !

Answer (score 12):

Suppose the special code will be added into java compiler to handle `forEach`. 
Then many similar questions could be asked. 
Why we cannot write `myArray.fill(0)`? Or `myArray.copyOfRange(from, to)`? Or `myArray.sort()`? 
`myArray.binarySearch()`? `myArray.stream()`? Practically every static method in `Arrays` 
interface could be converted into the corresponding method of the "array class". Why should JDK developers stop on
`myArray.forEach()`? Note however that every such method must be added not only into classlib specification,
but into Java Language Specification which is far more stable and conservative. Also this would mean that not only
the implementation of such methods would become part of specification, but also classes like `java.util.function.Consumer`
should be explicitly mentioned in JLS (which is the argument of proposed `forEach` method). 
Also note that new consumers would be necessary to add to the 
standard library like `FloatConsumer`, `ByteConsumer`, etc. for the corresponding array types. 
Currently the JLS rarely refers to the types outside of `java.lang` package (with some notable exceptions
like `java.util.Iterator`). This implies some stability layer. The proposed change is too drastic for Java language.

Also note that currently we have one method which could be called for arrays directly (and which implementation differs
from the `java.lang.Object`): it's `clone()` method. It actually adds some dirty parts into javac and even JVM
as it must be handled specially everywhere. This causes bugs (e.g. method references were incorrectly handled in Java 8 JDK-8056051). Adding more similar complexity into javac may introduce
even more similar bugs.

Such feature will probably be implemented in some not so near future as a part of 
[Arrays 2.0 initiative](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~jrose/pres/201207-Arrays-2.pdf).
The idea is to introduce some superclass for arrays which will be located in class library, so 
new methods could be added just by writing normal java code without tweaking javac/JVM. However,
this is also very hard feature as arrays are always treated specially in Java, and,
as far as I know it's unknown yet whether it will be implemented and when.

Comment: Thank you for a JDK-developer perspective! The lack of those other Collection methods on arrays does not bother me because they are visible only when one looks at Javadoc for collections (and even `java.lang.Object`) and wonders why not to 'bring them over' to arrays (sort of reverse engineering). Enhanced-for loops and `forEach`, OTOH, were natural candidates for availability on arrays and hence the question.

Comment: @KedarMhaswade, while I'm JDK developer, I'm actually a newbie here, so I more like outside person and my answer should not be considered as official. Probably Stuart Marks will comment on this during the AMA session (actually I've found this question via virtualJUG site).

Comment: @KedarMhaswade This question didn't get discussed in the VirtualJUG AMA, unfortunately. I also found this question via your posting on the VirtualJUG forum.